# Parsing JSON doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, parsing

The JS array containing JSON objects is in external file *pairs.js* which looks like this:

```
var objects =[{
    "name":"Joe",
    "age":"22"
  },{
    "name":"April",
    "age":"43"
  }, .......
];
```

I include the file in html like this:

```
<script src="pairs.js"></script>
```

Now my problem begins - I can't parse these objects. I've done it like this:

```
var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(objects);
//also tried: jQuery.parseJSON(objects[0]);
alert(obj.name);
```

But it won't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've used JavaScript literal syntax to create JavaScript objects. That isn't JSON. There's nothing to parse since it's already in the native object types of the programming environment.

Comment: I read the expression *JSON object* in this site about 20 times a day...

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON Object".  JSON is a *string representation* of an object (it just happens to be similar to the JavaScript object syntax).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've been trying to resolve this before asking here but obviously I'm still a greenhorn in web dev :) Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jQuery.parseJSON()` expects a string argument that contains JSON.  But you're passing it an already-formed object.  *You don't need to parse anything at all here.*  Just use `objects`.

Comment: Thank you, *alert(objects[0].name]* did it!

Answer (score 0):

`objects` is already a JavaScript object and parseJson() won't work in this case

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing a formed Object, so there is **no need** to parse it, just try using the object.